# Looking for symbology for NAICS codes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, symbology, business, standards

I am curious if anyone has come up or has a good graphic style they can share that is symbology for NAICS codes. I have a large dataset that I want to symbpolize based on the 2 digit NAICS industry code, but can't any sort of good or consistent stanard.
Any good sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are "three [NAICS] Business related .style files" that you can download from the **[ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/79037-NAICS-Business-Code-Symbology)**.

Comment: Nice catch; never thought of looking in the BA section.